# NPM Error on Laravel MIX

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, npm

So Im trying to do a build on laravel mix, it worked fine and now its just bulking out with random errors. I have tried deleting the Node_Modules folder and rerunning npm install but no joy.

And when I run npm run watch in terminal I get

```
* vue-echarts-v3/src/lite.vue in ./~/babel-loader/lib?{"cacheDirectory":true,"presets":[["env",{"modules":false,"targets":{"browsers":["> 2%"],"uglify":true}}]]}!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./resources/assets/components/index.vue, ./~/babel-loader/lib?{"cacheDirectory":true,"presets":[["env",{"modules":false,"targets":{"browsers":["> 2%"],"uglify":true}}]]}!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./resources/assets/components/orders/create_order.vue

To install it, you can run: npm install --save vue-echarts-v3/src/lite.vue
```

I then try to run  npm install --save vue-echarts-v3/src/lite.vue  and get the below error.

```
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /Users/GrahamDojo/sites/phobetor/vue-echarts-v3/src/lite.vue
npm ERR! Darwin 16.7.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "vue-echarts-v3/src/lite.vue"
npm ERR! node v7.9.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! path /Users/GrahamDojo/sites/phobetor/vue-echarts-v3/src/lite.vue
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/GrahamDojo/sites/phobetor/vue-echarts-v3/src/lite.vue'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/GrahamDojo/sites/phobetor/vue-echarts-v3/src/lite.vue'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/GrahamDojo/.npm/_logs/2017-11-21T08_25_04_481Z-debug.log
```

And my Package.json looks like so:

```
{
  "name": "Phobetor",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Vuejs based admin template",
  "main": "main.js",
  "private": true,
  "author": "The Tech Dojo",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "animejs": "^2.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "baguettebox.js": "^1.8.2",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^0.16.1",
    "chartist": "^0.10.1",
    "checkbox.css": "^1.1.3",
    "easy-pie-chart": "^2.1.7",
    "es6-promise": "^4.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fuse.js": "^3.0.5",
    "geolocator": "^2.1.1",
    "hover.css": "^2.2.0",
    "js-image-zoom": "^0.4.1",
    "mini-toastr": "^0.6.5",
    "parsleyjs": "^2.8.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "radiobox.css": "^1.0.1",
    "screenfull": "^3.3.1",
    "tether": "^1.4.1",
    "v-chartist": "^0.1.4",
    "vue": "^2.4.1",
    "vue-awesome-swiper": "^2.6.7",
    "vue-clip": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-codemirror": "^3.1.0",
    "vue-count-to": "^1.0.5",
    "vue-echarts-v3": "^1.0.4",
    "vue-form": "^4.3.4",
    "vue-fullcalendar": "^1.0.9",
    "vue-images-loaded": "^1.1.2",
    "vue-js-toggle-button": "^1.2.0",
    "vue-multiselect": "2.0.0-beta.13",
    "vue-quill-editor": "^2.2.4",
    "vue-router": "^2.7.0",
    "vue-slider-component": "^2.4.2",
    "vue-tables-2": "^0.6.77",
    "vue2-animate": "^1.0.4",
    "vue2-dropzone": "^2.3.5",
    "vue2-google-maps": "^0.7.9",
    "vueisotope": "^3.1.0",
    "vuejs-datepicker": "^0.9.16",
    "vuetrend": "^0.2.2",
    "vuex": "^2.3.1",
    "weathericons": "^2.0.10"
  }
}
```

Comment: update `package.jason`, you can do `npm` Rebuild.

Comment: Update what and where?

Comment: Step 1- Do fresh LARAVEL project download.
Step 2- Replace package.json content , with the content from the link provided above.
Step 3- Through command prompt - npm install --no-bin-links
Step 4- Through command prompt - npm rebuild